# golang command works like a forkbomb

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, golang

When i run `go run someapp` or `go version` and all other go commands, it works like a forkbomb. It reproduces itself, until my RAM and SWAP is full.

[image: Example]

How to prevent it?

Please note, that i changed the dir `/usr/lib/node_modules/` as below:

```
root:nodecli rwxrwxr-x.
```

Anyway, i am calling `go` without superuser rights.

Comment: Simply fixed it by uninstalling the nodejs package and installing go via debian repositories.

Comment: Please [do not edit your original question to include an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216722/271445). Instead, fix your post so it can be reopened, then post an answer on your question.